# VBA ADO Disconnected Recordset Updatebatch Deleted Records

Tags: ado, recordset

1. open a recordset from Access DB Table
2. disconnect it
3. add, edit, delete some records
4. connect back to Access DB
5. Updatebatch

The update adds new records, edits edited but does NOT delete deleted records.
Official statement is that deleted records are not accessible when you move away from them.
Does this mean that deleted records needs to be handled separately to be reflected in the main Access DB?

I would be helpful for support.

Answer (score 0):

To UpdateBatch All changes including deleted records set Filter property to adFilterPendingRecords.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).